# Reassign textbox.text on bindingsource currentitem change event

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, ado.net, bindingsource

I am just learning bindingsources etc. I have added my textbox databindings like so:

```
txtTitle.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingNavigator1.BindingSource.Current, "Title");
```

When the user clicks the next button on the navigator do I have to handle the bindingsource currentitem changed event to say

```
txtTitle.Text = ((MyObject)bindingsource.CurrentItem).Title??
```

I would have thought this would be automatic as I have a lot of controls so seems tedious

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should bind to the bindingsource itself as in:

```
txtTitle.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingNavigator1.BindingSource, "Title");
```

Then you don't need to handle any further events. As you say, that would be tedious.

Comment: Thanks, I had already tried that but it errored. Seems ok now...weird!